# SVN PECL extension behaviour on timeout

Tags: php, svn, pecl

I have been discussing with a fellow developer about product deployment of a webbased product using the PECL SVN extension for PHP. The idea is to deploy the updates by pulling them from the SVN repository.

We have been running some tests with the SVN functions and they all worked great but discussing the solution we have come up with a potential problem that we couldn't find an answer to.

What happens with the SVN connection when the PHP script reaches the maximum execution time or is interrupted in another way? Does PHP start the SVN connection which then runs independently and is not dependant on the script that called it?

If the SVN connections depend on the script what happens if the script is interrupted while an SVN update or commit is running? This could potentially corrupt the updating process and leave the working copy between two revisions and/or with incomplete files.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Wouldnt it be more practical to use Phing, Ant, Maven or Capistrano and similar tools for deployment?

Comment: Yes. I have been reading about those (especially about Phing) and they seem to be a great solution for deployment. We currently exploring the possibilites. Thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not run the SVN related functions independently, they are like native functions. You can always extend the timeout on PHP with [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.set-time-limit.php)

I'm currently using those PHP functions to export a large repository with about 30MB and several thousand files without any (timout) problems. If you can use always the latest version of the SVN library on your machine and the PECL extension. There are a lot of bugfixes in the latest releases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was aware of the possibility to increase the timeout, but thanks for pointing that out. I was hoping to find out what happens if, be it through timeout or any other problem, the script fails after the svn update/commit has started.